# Parse.com SendGrid Cloud Module: Cannot send header param object

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, sendgrid

I am try to send an email through Parse.com's SendGrid cloud module with the *header* param in order to include some unique arguments about the email being sent.

```
var SendGrid = require("sendgrid");  
SendGrid.initialize(username, password);

SendGrid.sendEmail({
  to: request.params.to,
  from: request.params.from,
  subject: request.params.subject,
  html: request.params.html,
  headers: JSON.stringify({ "unique_args": { "newsletter": request.params.newsletter }})
}, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(httpResponse);
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse);
  }
});
```

This gets the error message: *JSON in headers is valid but incompatible*

When I don't Stringify the header, I receive this error:
*Uncaught Error: Can't form encode an Object*

More information about SendGrid Mail API: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

More information about Parse.com SendGrid Cloud Module: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#sendgrid

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for the header would actually be `x-smtpapi`. You also don't need to stringify the json for this case.

Full usage with your example is:

```
var SendGrid = require("sendgrid");  
SendGrid.initialize(username, password);

SendGrid.sendEmail({
  to: request.params.to,
  from: request.params.from,
  subject: request.params.subject,
  html: request.params.html,
  "x-smtpapi": { "unique_args": { "newsletter": request.params.newsletter }}
}, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(httpResponse);
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse);
  }
});
```

Docs for the lib are [here](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-parse). It is actually easier to create an email object and work with it through the provided methods.